# LM3150 Webench not matching with LTSpice?

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck, step-down

I'm trying to implement this design from Webench (5V @ 10A):

[image]

I'm using LTspice to simulate this design, but my results are bizarre, as shown here:

[image]

I have looked into this thread: [TI Webench and PSpice Conflicting Results for LM3150 Buck Converter](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/572979/ti-webench-and-pspice-conflicting-results-for-lm3150-buck-converter)

I'm still wondering if there's a solution for this issue. From what I saw from user Tony Stewart EE75: (https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/17574/tony-stewart-ee75), TI Webench and PSpice Conflicting Results for LM3150 Buck Converter, URL (version: 2021-06-26): https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/572984 , it's a feedback wiring error tied to GND, so does that mean PSpice can't simulate this behavior, but in practice I should get the 5V output if I were to breadboard this design?

Thank you for any help.

Comment: your LTspice design is wrong.. Pls fix it

Comment: I'm sorry, but where would it be wrong?

Comment: Your schematic is very difficult to read. Have you tried making the symbol looking just like the way you see it in the datasheet? It doesn't have to have the exact same order as the real life part has, but debugging will be easier. Those capacitors across `V1` are useless, unless you specified `Rser` (in either the caps or the source). Also, the `SS` cap is the "soft start", so you may need to wait longer for the output to "come alive". Not lastly, the model, itself, may have problems ; have you tried TINA or PSpice to see how they fare? Try `.opt method=gear`.

Comment: 1st review you have no damping resistance in any components, i.e. infinite Q